# Running android app in headless

Tags: android, android-emulator, headless

Can I run android app in headless emulator. I tried with am command but it showed NullPointer Exception. I think as it is a gui application I can't. Is there any way around? The emulator is so slow. It takes like 5-7 mins sometimes. I'm running gingerbread by the way.

Environment: I'm running from qemu source code. From android image and kernel image. The arguments to qemu emulator are something like this:

```
-sysdir ../../android-image -kernel ../../android-kernel/zImage -no-window -qemu -monitor stdio
```

Comment: Please add some more information. Are you running it directly via `android avd` or on a CI-Server? What command are you using? Generally it's possible to run an app within a headless emulator.

Comment: Can you provide the logcat of your NullPointerException?

Answer (score 2):

From `${android-sdk}/tools` run this command:

```
emulator -avd NAME_OF_EMULATOR -no-skin -no-audio -no-window
```

In this blog it is nicely explained: http://paulemtz.blogspot.cz/2013/05/android-testing-in-headless-emulator.html